# Modify XML using Xpath in SCALA

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

For the XML given below,

```
val doc =
<library>
  <videos>
    <vid>Head</vid>
    <video type="dvd">Seven</video>
    <video type="blue-ray">The fifth element</video>
    <video type="hardcover">Gardens of the moon</video>
  </videos>
  <books>
    <book type="softcover">Memories of Ice</book>
  </books>
</library>
```

Need to change the content in XPATH : `doc\("videos")\("vid")`
as `<video type="usb">one</video>`

Thus desired output is,

```
<library>
  <videos>
    <video type="usb">one</video>
    <video type="dvd">Seven</video>
    <video type="blue-ray">The fifth element</video>
    <video type="hardcover">Gardens of the moon</video>
  </videos>
  <books>
    <book type="softcover">Memories of Ice</book>
  </books>
</library>
```

Any ideas on modifying XML content using XPATH is welcome!

Comment: Idea of modifying XML using XPath is initially hopeless

Comment: @Andersson you mean impossible?

Comment: Yes. You need something like [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp)

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for the answer